# GooglePlay and package company name

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app in Play Market with package name, for example `com.mycompany.appone`. And I want to publish another app with package `com.mycompany.apptwo` **from another account**. Is it allowed? Or same company should publish all apps from the same account?

Comment: **why** should you use a different account?

Comment: Ya why not???  You should used the same account.

Comment: It's going to be production of the same apps (in general) for diffrent clients with personalization (design, some features). So, clients are not linked, why should they be on one account? In addition I think google may not approve this kind of apps from one account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is allowed**, although probably not recommended, simply because it might be confusing for users and developers.

Comment: Can you please share link where is it stated?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html Under `package` you can read more about how to choose a package name. It doesn't explicitly answer your question, but it doesn't forbid it, thus you can assume it is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

> You can use, its allowed.

But creating second account will charge same as it did for creating first account.